# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in line 179 (file doesn't have so many lines)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, php-shorttags

I'm getting the error-message while executing a .php-file which has just 177 lines.

Background: this is a Wordperfect-Install, that same page executes fine for other records, but in the record which causes issues, I'm demo-ing some new shortcodes. It is not unlikely that I made a fault in these developments, but that is all done outside of the "crashing" file, so I wonder why it would appear there (and with such a strange line-no.) and not in the source that I modified...

In `wp-config.php`, I have set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

**P.S:** The exact error msg is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\mytheme\single-record.php on line 179
```

Comment: If the file includes other files either explicitly with include/require(once) calls or implicitly through an autoloader, then the line number probably refers to the included file.

Comment: Would you mind showing us the exact error message?

Comment: You probably have an unclosed bracket somewhere.

Comment: Some `{}`s could be missing.

Comment: No include or require in that file, the IDE also reports no errors related to control-structures or brackets...

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a real problem and a legitimate question, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with the help of fellow dev I found the solution: the guy who wrote the original code had used the short opening tags in PHP '`<?`' and apparently support for these needs to be enabled in the PHP.INI (which I had not done, 'coz I do not like them). So, after updating all tags to "decent PHP", the error is gone!

Comment: thanks! Exactly what the problem is in my case - Lucky I found this, you've saved me a lot of time!